# How to get controls by dynamic name in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 5 dropdown with name postfix by 1,2,3...so on... How can i get name of these dropdown in javascript

```
var TotalLvl=document.getElementById('<%=dd_Designation_Level.ClientID%>').value;
for (var i = 1; i <= d; i++) {
   var DesLvl='Designation' +i;
   if ((document.getElementById('<%=' + DesLvl +'%>').value == "0")) {
      alert('Designation' + i 'should be selected');
   }
}
```

i am not able to do this by this dynamic name DesLvl

Comment: from ur given code its clear that 'DesLvl' is js variable and not server script variable, u may try this: document.getElementById(DesLvl).value

Comment: @Arvind thanx for your response but script is getting failed because of this

Comment: wat do u get as error?

Comment: its just skipping java script validation part and go directly to cs code